# Check how many times a column value is repeating in power bi

Tags: powerbi

Count the number of times a column value is repeating and add another column to get the repeated count.

```
For Example:
Name   repeated count
raj     1
raghav  1 
raghav  2
raman   1
```

Comment: add it where? To the End? Please be more specific and show us what you have done so far to resolve this problem

Comment: Use Group BY and Count for your purpose.